# Autosizing while rotating device (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, rotation

I'm currently fighting with the following problem. Maybe someone of you knows an answer. I think it's not difficult, but i have no clue why it is like it is.

Here's the problem:

First everything looks as it should, but after rotating the device...

[image]

.. the textfield disapears under the navigation-bar... Any ideas? :)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to use the struts and springs in the size inspector?

Comment: Yes i have already tried that. It looks like the view (which contains the textfield and label's) moves under the navigationbar...

Comment: The view that contains the textField and Labels, is it flexibleHeight? I assume it has a fixed height and tries to squeeze it in the landscape mode. Also (lower half of) the buttons on nav bar look weird in landscape. are those buttons not being centered?

Comment: Thank's for your tips.. Just one question.. How can i check whether the view is fixed or not?